# Readme.txt seems to be cached but not the version

Tags: plugin-development, updates, translation, readme

I know there are a lot of questions on readme.txt in Wordpress but having not succeeded using Google-Fu, I thought I'd ask a question to see if anyone else has come across this.

I have created a WordPress Plugin which is available on the marketplace, I then wanted to upgrade it which i did through updating the version of the plugin in the main.php file, as well as the readme.txt and created the tag version of that release all in one commit.

After doing the commit, within a few minutes the correct information was being displayed on the plugin page in the wordpress.org marketplace directory.

All good so far right? I was encountering some users who were still seeing the one before last readme.txt version. After digging, it turns out that they were not going to wordpress.org/plugins, they were on the specific language version. So in one example en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins.

For some reason, the en-gb version of my plugin page, has the readme.txt from two versions ago, but the version that appears on the right hand side of that page, with the "Last Updated" and "Active Installs" is correct from the most recent version. It's just the actual text content of the page that is out of date.

Prodding some more, the Italian version of the page is fine, but the Spanish / French versions were not. ( Granted i haven't put translations in but it was just out of curiosity )

In a moment of desperation having run out of things to try, i directly updated the old versions readme.txt in the tag to see if it was just stuck looking at the wrong one but that has not had any impact.

Can anyone confirm if this is just a cacheing issue that will eventually be overwritten given time? or is there something out of whack? I'm more just confused that the main Wordpress.org page has been updated, as has the Italian page, but the en-gb, French etc has not. It just seems odd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Known bug, working on it:

https://meta.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/2750

Always check the tickets first.

Comment: Thanks for that Otto, I didn't know that existed, will add that to my bookmarks. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It can be caching issue but as major changes have made in the WordPress plugins repository recently, this can also cause this issue. I had faced similar issue recently so i contacted wp.org plugins support and they resolved the issue for me so i also recommend you to contact plugins support on plugins@wordpress.org

Comment: Thanks for the info. I've dropped them an e-mail with the info to see if that  will help. Will mark as answer if ( hopefully ) it gets resolved